# Install Windows 7

Tags: windows, system-installation

I'm running ubuntu 13.10. But I guess I need to go back to Windows 7. Its so easy to install Ubuntu from a bootable usb because of a program. But I can't find any similar windows program that I've used to install ubuntu that runs on ubuntu. Can I still install Windows 7? I do have the Windows 7 ISO file with me. Help please.

Comment: yes,you can install windows alongside ubuntu.Try to create bootable windows usb in Ubuntu through winusb.see http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention if you're using a dual boot, so I assume you only have Ubuntu currently installed to your system.

#### Option 1: If want a dual-boot...

..you'll have to install Windows 7 to a new partition. This install will overwrite the boot sector so that the previously installed Ubuntu will not be recognized during boot, and you'd have to fix this using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tools/disk.

#### Option 2: If you don't want Ubuntu anymore...

..you can delete Ubuntu partitions with Windows 7 installation disk and create a Windows' filesystem (`fat` or preferably `ntfs`) and install Windows there.

#### Option 3: Use virtualization software to install Windows OS as a guest in your Ubuntu sysem:

Among the ones available out there, I use [Oracle's VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) <sup>([wikipedea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox))</sup>. This link explains [how to install VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation).

Answer (score -1):

What you do is install windows 7 on one hard drive then reinstall Ubuntu I found this the easiest way of doing it.